# Haskell: a return before is cancelled out by a monad after. How?

Tags: haskell, return, monads, type-inference

How do I understand the statement `return 1 getLine`? It passes type-checking, and seems identical to `1`. How are `getLine` and `return` "cancelling" each other out? It doesn't make sense to me at all.

```
Prelude> :t return 1
return 1 :: (Monad m, Num a) => m a

Prelude> :t return 1 getLine            -- why is it not a type error?
return 1 getLine :: Num t => t          

Prelude> return 1 getLine               
1                                       -- whatever happened to getLine?
```

Also, how come the end product is "pure" even though it involves a `getLine`?

Comment: It takes the `instance Monad ((->) a)` here as monad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How do I understand the statement `return 1 getLine`?*

By first noticing that `return 1 getLine` is actually ***`(return 1)`***`getLine`.

This means that `return 1` is a function, since it accepts an additional argument, and functions are monadic values too *(that's why it's not a type error)*.

Thus we must unify

```
return   ::  Monad m   => a  -> m  a
return 1 :: (Monad m, Num a) => m  a
return 1 ::           Num a  => r -> a     -- Monad (r ->)
```

so that `m a ~ r -> a` and thus **`m ~ (->) r`** (which is the proper way to write `(r ->)` which is itself an invalid syntax).

For functions, `return = const` and so we have

```
return 1 getline 
= const 1 getline 
= const 1 undefined
= 1
```

because `const` is defined as

```
const :: a -> b -> a
const    x    y =  x
```

*(and that's how `getLine` gets ignored).*

---

In general, the functions Monad instance is defined so that

```
do { a <- f ; b <- foo a ; return (bar a b) } x
```

is the same as

```
let { a = f x ; b = foo a x } in bar a b  -- const (bar a b) x
```

And that's the reason for `return` being defined as `const`.

This means that `return` and `getLine` do *not* "cancel each other out". That's the doing of `return` only, by virtue of being applied to a second argument, *whatever that is*, even one which is `undefined`.

So `getLine` belonging to the `IO` "monad", as you write in the question, is *irrelevant*. Everything is a value in Haskell, and `getLine` is just another value as well. And it is a pure value at that; it just describes an "impure" I/O action, but by itself it is just another value, simply used as an argument here. Only when `getLine` appears in `main` in an appropriate position (or in other code that appears in main, recursively) is it "run", i.e. the computation it describes is actually performed. Here this is not the case.

The monad in play here is the functions monad, to which this `return` belongs.

---

As to the purity question, monads are not pure or impure themselves. A type which implements a Monad can be *either* pure *or* impure. Functions happen to be pure.

What Monads do is  *separate* the pure from the potentially impure.

But that's actually what Functors do as well. Monads, specifically, allow then for the *intermingling chaining* of the *pure-->impure-->pure-->impure-->....* bits, while preserving their separation (again, the "impure" bits can actually be pure themselves as well; the important thing is the *separation* between the two "worlds").

Answer (score 5):

If you write `return 1 getLine`, that means that `return 1` should be a function that takes `getLine` as parameter.

We are lucky, because there is an [instance for `Monad` with a function `((->) r)` [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#line-986). Indeed:

> ```
> -- | @since 2.01
> instance Applicative ((->) r) where
>     pure = const
>     (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
>     liftA2 q f g x = q (f x) (g x)
>
> -- | @since 2.01
> instance Monad ((->) r) where
>     f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
> ```

`(->) r` is a more canonical form for `r -> …`. It is thus a function with `r` as parameter type, and if applied to a type parameter `a` for example, then `((->) r) a` is equivalent to `r -> a`.

For this instance of `Monad`, `return` has the same implementation as `pure` which is `const`. This thus means that:

```
return 1 getLine
```

is equivalent to:

```
   const 1 getLine
→ (\_ -> 1) getLine
→ 1
```